# How do I customize my own select options in Gravity Forms?

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I have two select fields in this custom Gravity Form that I've been struggling with. The first field is a list of webinars. The second field is a list of the webinar dates. Which dates show depend on which webinar you choose. I'm planning on sorting that list with jQuery but in order to do that I need to add an attribute to the select options in the webinar dates select field. At present, I can't figure out how to modify GF's select options function. This is what my custom function looks like currently:

```
//Populate Webinars form field for Webinar dates
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_2', 'populate_webinar_dates' );
function populate_webinar_dates( $form ) {

    foreach( $form[ 'fields' ] as &$field ) {

        if( $field[ 'type' ] != 'select' || strpos( $field[ 'cssClass' ], 'populate-dates' ) === false )
            continue;

        $posts = new WP_Query( 'numberposts=-1&post_status=publish&post_type=vtl_webinar' );

        $choices = '<option value=" ">Select a date</option>';

        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
            while ( has_sub_field( 'dates_available' ) ) :
                $post_dates = array( 'date' => get_sub_field( 'date' ) );
                $post_title = array( 'name' => str_replace( " ", "-", get_the_title() ) );
                //$choices[] = array( 'text' => $post_dates['date'], 'value' => $post_dates['date'] );
                $choices = '<option value="' . $post_dates['date'] . '" data-id="' . $post_title . '">' . $post_dates['date'] . '</option>';
            endwhile;                
        endwhile;

        $field[ 'choices' ] = $choices;

    }

    return $form;
}
```

Obviously, this line doesn't work:

```
$choices = '<option value="' . $post_dates['date'] . '" data-id="' . $post_title . '">' . $post_dates['date'] . '</option>';
```

It's expecting parameters similar to the commented form above that line but you can't just add your own attributes to that line. You have to work according to an existing set of parameters that GF is looking for. Can someone help me out with this? I just need to get the data attribute in the options.

Answer (score 2):

I was going about this the wrong way. To get the custom options that I was trying to create, I used the following code instead of what I posted above.

```
add_filter("gform_field_input", "webinar_date_option", 10, 2);
function webinar_date_option($input, $field, $value, $lead_id, $form_id) {
    if ( $field["cssClass"] == "populate-dates" ) {
        $input = '<select name="input_2" id="input_2_2" class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="2">';
        $posts = new WP_Query( 'numberposts=-1&post_status=publish&post_type=vtl_webinar' );
        $input .= '<option value=" ">Select Date</option>';
        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
            while ( has_sub_field( 'dates_available' ) ) :
                $post_dates = array( 'date' => get_sub_field( 'date' ) );
                $date_id = array( 'id' => get_the_ID() );
                $input .= '<option value="'. $post_dates['date'] .'" data-id="'. $date_id['id'] .'">'. $post_dates['date'] .'</option>';
            endwhile;
        endwhile;
        $input .= '</select>';
    }
    return $input;
}
```